# jQuery hide() flicker

Tags: php, jquery, hide, flicker

I have a PHP script which runs validation on a form with some inputs. I wanted to hide() the errors then have them fade in (rather than just have them appear) once the page reloads.

The issue i'm having is that, although the script works...I get a slight flicker of the error fields as the page is loading.

```
<div class="error">sample error</div>

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    if($('div.error').length > 0)

    {

       $('div.error').hide();

        if($('div.error:hidden'))
        {
            $('div.error').delay('1000').fadeIn('2000');   
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most of the code is not needed actually. Since you are hiding the div, no need to check if it's hidden, and fadeIn() will do nothing if the div is visible. The check for elements exsitence is also not needed when using build-in jQuery functions, altough it's a good practive.

Answer (score 1):

Is your error box hidden before the page is loaded?

Looking at your code, it will be present, then hidden by JavaScript when the document is ready, then faded in.

I'd reccomend you add a class to your error field called `hidden` and declare this in your stylesheed as `.hidden{ display:none;}`

Then adapt your js to be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    if($('div.error').length > 0)

    {

       $('div.error').hide().removeClass('hidden');

        if($('div.error:hidden'))
        {
            $('div.error').delay('1000').fadeIn('2000');   
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this solution only javascript dependant? 
I don't want to hide the fields directly in the stylesheet for people without javascript.

Comment: Yes indeed it is but likely the only way to get rid of your flicker

Comment: For errors, I think a better behavior that works without JS would be to show the error when the page loads and potentially fade out after a while

Comment: A possible solution is to do what Modernizr do. They add `class="no-js"` to the HTML tag and then using javascript (not on the onload, but as soon as it's available) to remove this. You can then use CSS to handle both. i.e. .error { display: none; } .no-js .error { display: block; } this way it gracefully degrades if no javascript is available.